# Extract table data (unit column) in selenium using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriverwait, text-extraction

Can someone help me with this

I'm trying to extract the unit alone from the table on this website https://opennem.org.au/facility/au/NEM/DEIBDL/?range=all&interval=1y

This is what I tried, I can be only able to extract the first one in the table. I need all the units on the table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver108.exe')
driver.get("https://opennem.org.au/facility/au/NEM/DEIBDL/?range=all&interval=1y")
driver.maximize_window()
toolTip = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='unit-name has-tooltip']"))).text
print(toolTip)
```

Output I'm expecting is

BDL01
BDL02

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for element text you need to wait for element visibility.
Also, since there are multiple elements you need to extract the texts from you need to use `visibility_of_all_elements_located` expected condition.
This returns you a **list** of web elements you need to iterate over extracting their texts.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

url = 'https://opennem.org.au/facility/au/NEM/DEIBDL/?range=all&interval=1y'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
#
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='unit-name has-tooltip']")))
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

The output is:

```
BDL01
BDL02
```